# Youtube API: Retrieving Live Events hyperlink

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am retrieving the Live events from my YouTube channel using the [Retrieving Live Events API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_retrieving_live_events). I don't see anywhere the actual hyperlink of the video. I am trying to create a list of my upcoming events using this API, but want to add the hyperlink to YouTube.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This API is going to get deprecated and it's platform is already did. I suggest you to move to [Live API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/).

Either way your watch link is same as other youtube video links. Once you have a broadcast(event) id, it will be.

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={EVENT_ID}
```